# Android custom ArrayAdapter with only 2 ViewHolders

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

This custom ArrayAdapter to my ListView fills it's field correctly, but it sets colors completely wrong.
Only 2 ViewHolders are creating and i have max 10 elements in ListView, so other elements take colors from already created holders. Can you please help me how to make this working?

```
public class MistakesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView question;
    TextView answer1;
    TextView answer2;
    TextView answer3;
    TextView answer4;

    ViewHolder(View v){
        this.question = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.question);
        this.answer1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        this.answer2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        this.answer3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        this.answer4 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.answer4);
    }
}

public MistakesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Data> data) {
    super(context, 0, data);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    Data data = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mistakes_list,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    try {
        holder.question.setText(data._question);
        holder.answer1.setText(data._answer1);
        holder.answer2.setText(data._answer2);
        holder.answer3.setText(data._answer3);
        holder.answer4.setText(data._answer4);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (!positionWas.contains(data._question)) {
        positionWas.add(data._question);
        colorTextViews(position, holder);
    }
    return v;
}

void colorTextViews(int position, ViewHolder holder) {

   for (int i = stopIndex; i < wrongAnswers.size(); i++) {
       if (wrongAnswers.get(i)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "position " + position + "i " + i);
            indexRight = answersId.get(position);
            indexWrong = userAnswers.get(position);
            stopIndex = i + 1;
            color(position, holder);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void color(int position, ViewHolder holder) {

    Log.d(TAG, "color position: " + position +  ", red: " + indexWrong + ", green " + indexRight);
    switch (indexRight) {
        case 1:
            holder.answer1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case 2:
            holder.answer2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case 3:
            holder.answer3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
        case 4:
            holder.answer4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            break;
    }

    switch (indexWrong) {
        case 1:
            holder.answer1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case 2:
            holder.answer2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case 3:
            holder.answer3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            break;
        case 4:
            holder.answer4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: And where is colorTextViews(position, holder); method code ? Can you provide it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing the convertView nature, you have to ensure you reset the styles of all the changable UI elements   before reusing the convertView, it is only necessary if you change the styles (colors, etc) on the view that you inflated per row basis.

So if you ensure that  you always execute the '**colorTextViews(position, holder)**' (put it outside of this '*if condition*') setting the proper colors according to the current data state, it will work the way you want.

or simplifying like this:

```
    Answer correctAnswer = ...;

    holder.question.setText(data._question);
    holder.answer1.setText(data._answer1);
    holder.answer1.setTextColor(data._answer1.equals(correctAnswer)? Color.BLUE : Color.RED);
    holder.answer2.setText(data._answer2);
    holder.answer2.setTextColor(data._answer2.equals(correctAnswer)? Color.BLUE : Color.RED);
    holder.answer3.setText(data._answer3);
    holder.answer3.setTextColor(data._answer3.equals(correctAnswer)? Color.BLUE : Color.RED);
    holder.answer4.setText(data._answer4);
    holder.answer4.setTextColor(data._answer4.equals(correctAnswer)? Color.BLUE : Color.RED);
```